# Grafana - Single alert rule for multiple instances of a library panel

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts

I have multiple dashboards sharing the same library panel, say "CPU Load". Each dashboard has a different Prometheus Data Source and customer ID. Both `datasource` and `customerID` are variables in the dashboard settings, hence the library panel is configured like this (simplified):

```
Data Source: ${datasource}
Query: cpu_load{customer="$customerID"}
```

I want to create a single alert rule to trigger an alert whenever CPU load is above a certain threshold in **any** of the dashboards where the library panel "CPU Load" is present, instead of creating one Alert Rule for each instance of the panel with hardcoded `datasource` and `customerID`.

Is this even possible? I'm using Grafana 9.4.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Grafana [doesn't support variables in alerting rules](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/alerting-rules/create-grafana-managed-rule/#single-and-multi-dimensional-rule).

> **Note:** Grafana does not support alert queries with template variables. More information is available at https://community.grafana.com/t/template-variables-are-not-supported-in-alert-queries-while-setting-up-alert/2514.

Not to mention data source variables, to create alerts over multiple sources.

You'll need to define a per-data-source alert.